# Test Set Skipped issue on Round B, Kickstart 2019

Tags: java

I participated in Round B, Kickstart 2019, and had issues with **test sets being skipped** for every submission I made. I was wondering what would be causing the issue as it is working locally, and the logic seems right based on the analysis provided once the round was over.

Edit: I apologize for the confusion I made earlier! Here's the exact script I submitted which includes the class declaration and import statements. The reason I didn't include them before is that I somehow thought the problem is related to how I set up the main method. It is compiling when I run tests on their platform as well. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the feedback anyhow!

Edit: I've included a screenshot of my submission below as well!
[image: Screenshot of the submission]

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
        int T = in.nextInt();
        for (int t = 1; t <= T; t++) {
            int N = in.nextInt(); // blocks
            int Q = in.nextInt(); // questions
            in.nextLine();
            String S = in.nextLine();
            int K = 0;
            for (int q = 1; q <= Q; q++) {
                int L = in.nextInt();
                int R = in.nextInt();
                String sub = S.substring(L-1, R);
                if (isPalidromable(sub)) K++;
            }
            System.out.printf("Case #%d: %d\n", t, K);
        }

    }

    private static boolean isPalidromable(String sub) {
        int i = 0;
        for (char c: sub.toCharArray()) {
            i ^= c;
        }
        return i == 0 || 'A' <= i && i <= 'Z';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code and instructions or data necessary to reproduce the problem. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It is Building Palindromes problem appeared in this year's Kickstart, Round B. I could copy and paste the problem if you wish! My question was, my code seems to be working locally, but somehow the tests are being skipped on their platform when I submitted the code. It is compiling, and the output matches when I run tests on their platform as well. Now I'm thinking perhaps I missed some of the edge cases. Please let me know if this doesn't clear up the confusion!

Comment: This does seem a bit clearer.  I would suggest making it clear in the topic, like maybe "Why does my code run run differently when I submit it to Kickstart 2019 than when I run it locally?".  I'm still not sure this is on-topic for S.O.  I suppose it might be since this can be seen as a developer tools problem.  I don't know anything about this process, so I can't help you myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the FAQ and Rules before participating in such competitions. Online programming competitions provide important information related to testing environment, how you should code in each language, etc.

From [Kick Start 2019 FAQ](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/faq#faq-coding-content):

> **If I use Java or Scala, how should I structure my code?**
>
> You must name your main class Solution (with exactly that capitalization). It must contain a public main method. Furthermore, your code must not contain any package definitions. (Note: Package declarations are allowed in Kotlin.)

Also there should be correct imports in order to read from stdin and write to stdout. Example also from Kick Start 2019 FAQ:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
    int t = in.nextInt(); // Scanner has functions to read ints, longs, strings, chars, etc.
    for (int i = 1; i <= t; ++i) {
      int n = in.nextInt();
      int m = in.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Case #" + i + ": " + (n + m) + " " + (n * m));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the feedback! I've updated my question for more clarity. Could you please have a look if possible?

Comment: Hmm... did you correctly select the Language before submission?
A screenshot of your submissions list would be helpful too.

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I've included the screenshot of my submission above for your reference (I've selected Java (Open SDK) as the language option). I just wanted to know what would possibly be the issue so that I can do better on Round C :) Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It turns out that Test Set Skipped means all the hidden test sets are being skipped which happens when any of the visible test sets have failed. Thanks again for your time and I hope you didn't spend too much time on this thread... :)

Comment: Yes. relating to the screenshot, that is what exactly happened... You got WA (Wrong Answer) as test result for the Visible Test Set so the testing for Hidden Test Set are skipped.  
BTW, your function that checks whether the String passed as parameter is palindrome or not is not valid for this problem.

Comment: try passing "ACE" as the parameter for your function. Pay attention to what happens when doing the bit-wise XOR operator.